# Chtml CheckBox click on checkbox but still marked as unchecked not changing.. Submitting through ajax

Tags: php, jquery, yii

```
    <?php echo CHtml::checkBox('markComplete', FALSE , 
                    array(
                    'class' => 'markComplete',
                    'id'=> 'markComplete'.$events['id'],                        
                    'ajax' => array(
                                    'url'=>$this->createUrl('/events/events/MarkComplete'),
                                    'data'=>'event_status_on='.$events['id'],
                                    'type'=>'POST',
                                    'beforeSend' => 'js:function(){   

                                        var idSelector = $("#markComplete'.$events['id'].'");   
                                        var check = idSelector.is(":checked");  
                                        var child = idSelector.parent("td");
                                        var parent = $(child).parent("TR");
                                        $(parent).css("opacity","0.5");


                                    }',
                                    'success'=>'js:function(resp) {                                                                         
                                        $("#right").prepend(resp);

                                        return true;                                        
                                    }'
                                    ),
                                )

                            );

    ?>
```

Chtml CheckBox click on checkbox but still marked as unchecked not changing.. if i change it to TRUE then it not change into FALSE... Submit it thrugh AJAX... Getting response perfectly.

Comment: Try rewording your problem, that doesn't make a lot of sense to me. I'm not sure what you're changing to true or what repsonse you're expecting / getting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no error in your code, but the onclick handler that is finally generated for the checkBox returns false by default. Check your generated html, and you'll see this:

```
jQuery('body').undelegate('#markComplete_someId','click').delegate('#markComplete_someId','click',function(){jQuery.ajax({'url':'/something','data':'event_status_on=someId','type':'POST','beforeSend':function(){
     var idSelector = $("#markComplete");
     var check = idSelector.is(":checked");
     var child = idSelector.parent("td");
     var parent = $(child).parent("TR");
     $(parent).css("opacity","0.5");
},
'success':function(resp) {
      $("#right").prepend(resp);
      return true;
},'cache':false});
 return false; // this line changes everything!!
});
```

That `return false;` in the end prevents the default *onclick event* behavior of any html element. This is mentioned in the [documentation for the clientChange method](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHtml#clientChange-detail). You'll see that it allows us to specify certain special attributes for htmlOptions, such as `'ajax'` that you have already used, and also `'return'`, that specifies what the onclick handler should return, which is false by default, we can change this to return true, by adding the `'return'` property like this:

```
 <?php echo CHtml::checkBox('markComplete', FALSE , 
                array(
                   'class' => 'markComplete',
                   'id'=> 'markComplete'.$events['id'],                        
                   'ajax' => array( /* add your code */ ),
                   'return' => true // add return like this
                )
   );
?>
```

That will make it work.